# TypeError: Can't convert 'DoubleVar' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am creating a simple GUI program to measure time from a certain event. I am getting an error:

> /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/str8/str8.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/str8/str8.py", line 51, in 
>       app = App(root)   File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/str8/str8.py", line 22, in **init**
>       Label(self, text=measurement + ": " + self.counters[measurement], font='Verdana 8').grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky=W) TypeError: Can't
>   convert 'DoubleVar' object to str implicitly
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I have tried this:

```
Label(self, text=measurement + ": " + str(self.counters[measurement]), font='Verdana 8').grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

...but it gives me this:

[GUI program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXNdN.png)

Here is what I have done:

```
# str8.py
#   Program to count time from a certain event

from tkinter import *
from datetime import *


class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid(sticky = N + W + E + S)

        Label(self, text = 'You have been STR8 for:', font="Verdana 8 bold").grid(row=0, sticky=W)

        self.counters = dict()
        measurements = [ 'Years', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds' ]

        for i, measurement in enumerate(measurements):
            self.counters[measurement] = DoubleVar()
            Label(self, text=measurement + ": " + self.counters[measurement], font='Verdana 8').grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.counters[measurement].set(0)

        Button(self,
               text="EXIT",
               font="Verdana 8",
               height=1,
               width=19,
               command=quit).grid(row=7, column=0)

        self.increment()

    def increment(self):
        event = datetime(2017, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0)
        today = datetime.now()

        str8 = today - event
        self.counters['Seconds'].set(round(str8.total_seconds(), 2))
        self.counters['Minutes'].set(round(str8.total_seconds()/ 60, 2))
        self.counters['Hours'].set(round(str8.total_seconds() / 3600, 2))
        self.counters['Days'].set(round(str8.total_seconds() / (3600 * 24), 2))
        self.counters['Weeks'].set(round(str8.total_seconds() / (3600 * 24 * 7), 2))
        self.counters['Years'].set(round(str8.total_seconds() / (3600 * 24 * 7 * 52), 2))

        self.after(1000, self.increment)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.title("STR8")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Label can display some text using the `text` argument, OR it can display the value from a tkinter variable like a DoubleVar using the `textvariable` argument. It cannot do both. Either use this:

```
lbl = Label(self, text=measurement + ": ", font='Verdana 8')
lbl.grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Or this:

```
lbl = Label(self, textvariable=self.counters[measurement], font='Verdana 8')
lbl.grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Edit: A solution to your problem would be to make your own type of Label that can handle both:

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime

class FormatLabel(tk.Label):
    '''A new type of Label widget that allows both a text and textvariable'''
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self.textvariable = kwargs.pop('textvariable', tk.StringVar(master))
        self.text = kwargs.pop('text', '{}')
        self.textvariable.trace('w', self.update_text)
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

    def update_text(self, *args):
        self.config(text=self.text.format(self.textvariable.get()))

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text = 'You have been STR8 for:', font="Verdana 8 bold")
        lbl.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.W)

        self.counters = dict()
        measurements = [ 'Years', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds' ]

        for i, measurement in enumerate(measurements):
            self.counters[measurement] = tk.DoubleVar()
            lbl = FormatLabel(self,
                text=measurement + ": {:.2f}", # set the rounding here
                textvariable = self.counters[measurement],
                font='Verdana 8')
            lbl.grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
            self.counters[measurement].set(0)

        btn = tk.Button(self,
               text="EXIT",
               font="Verdana 8",
               height=1,
               width=19,
               command=quit)
        btn.grid(row=7, column=0)

        self.increment()

    def increment(self):
        event = datetime(2017, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0)
        today = datetime.now()

        str8 = (today - event).total_seconds()
        self.counters['Seconds'].set(str8)
        self.counters['Minutes'].set(str8 / 60.)
        self.counters['Hours'].set(str8 / 3600.)
        self.counters['Days'].set(str8 / (3600. * 24))
        self.counters['Weeks'].set(str8 / (3600. * 24 * 7))
        self.counters['Years'].set(str8 / (3600. * 24 * 7 * 52))

        self.after(1000, self.increment)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title("STR8")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note I also fixed some other parts of your code; most notably that you should not use wildcard imports (`from module import *`), you should not layout widgets on the same line as you define them, and that you should try not to repeat code.

Comment: Then I would get a huge gap between the labels, that's the reason why I tried to combine the two of these into one label. Come on, a solution to my problem must be very simple.

Comment: Simple, no. But doable. I edited my answer to show you one way.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that's the spirit!

Comment: ...and when it comes to importing, why is that? I'm still a newbie as you can see.

Comment: Why no wildcard imports? In short, it gets confusing and hard to read very quickly. Basically, in your code, the reader cannot know if "Label" is defined in the code or from one of the wildcard imports. Also, you don't know what you are importing. What if datetime decides to implement a constant "W"? Since that import comes second, it will overwrite the "W" from tkinter. You are going to get errors and be very frustrated because you think you are using `tkinter.W` when you are actually using `datetime.W`. It's against PEP8 as well.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thank you very much once again.